# export category and sub-category

Tags: export

I'm trying to export a specific category with it's sub-categories.
However, Wordpress export option allows either to export all of the categories or to export one specific category at a time. 
Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

- export all
- import on a blank install (e.g.: in your computer)
- delete the unwanted ones
- export again